# Laravel 9 ошибка типов при обращении к методу (который используется Request) через фасады

Tags: laravel

Имеется контроллера A использующий Request:

```
use App\Http\Requests\TestRequest;

class A extends Controller {
    public function test(TestRequest $request)
    {
        return 'Yes';
    }
}
```

и контроллер B который пытается вызвать функцию test() из контроллера A;

```
class B extends Controller {
    public function beta(Request $request, A $a)
    {
        dd($a->test($request->all()));
    }
}
```

При попытке обращения к методу test() из контроллера A возвращается ошибка:

```
Argument #1 ($request) must be of type App\\Http\\Requests\\TestRequest, array given, called in C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Project\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\BController.php on line 25
```

В самом Request никаких правил валидации я не описывал, используется laravel 9, почему возвращается эта ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

В метод test надо передавать Request, ты передаешь результат метода all(), который возвращает массив

Comment: При передаче Request вызывается ошибка: Argument #1 ($request) must be of type App\\Http\\Requests\\TestRequest, Illuminate\\Http\\Request given

Comment: $a->test($request)

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно потому что TestRequest - это не Request.

Простым языком у вас написано что контроллер А в методе test принимает у себя на входе объекты типа TestRequest.

Затем в контроллере Б вы пытаетесь воткнуть в метод test объект Request, а это уже не одно и тоже.

Решение какое:
Либо измените метод beta на

```
public function beta(TestRequest $request, A $a)
{
    dd($a->test($request));
}
```

Либо пишите свой интерфейс...